# Is RoboCup still vivant and significant robotic issue?

Tags: soccer

A couple years ago RoboCup competitions seems to be quite vivant issue. Now when I'm looking for some info about it, it seems to be some kind of insignificant but this may be only my first impression (I was looking for 2D simulator league and it seems that it does not even exist anymore).

So is RoboCup still alive and significant robotic issue?

Comment: I voted to close this question as "Primarily opinion based" because it seems like you are trying to provoke a discussion, which is more suitable for chat.

Comment: @Chuck The worst thing is you may be right :)